# UIPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect not displaying correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller

I am loading a popover view that displays the camera view. everything works however it dose not dsplay any bigger than a playing card on the iPad. No matter what I do I cannot resize it only change its position.

This is the code I use

```
[self.popOver presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(44, 6, 111, 111) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

How can I adjust the size?

### Update

This is what my whole method looks like:

```
- (void) cameraButtonSelected
{
    // create picker
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    picker.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(400.0, 400.0);

    if (picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {
        CGFloat scaleFactor=1.3f;
        picker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * -90 / 180.0), scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
    }

    // create popover
    self.popOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
    [self.popOver presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(44, 6, 111, 111) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try settings this property to the controller contained in popover

```
someViewController.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(200.0, 200.0)
```

try using

```
preferredContentSize
```

property.

sorry I don't have a mac on me to check it

Comment: I have updated my code.. I tried using the line of code you gave me but it didnt do anything.. could you check to see if I have used it correctly?

Comment: Yea I used preferredContentSize as the first one you suggested has been deprecated. so I am still in the same position this view is sitll behaving oddly.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to set the size in viewWillAppear:

```
 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.popover.preferredContentSize = ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked for me, so I resized the popoverController after displaying it like this:

```
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:cell.mediaComment.frame
                                   inView:cell
                 permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight
                                 animated:YES];
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.05 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    popoverController.contentViewController.preferredContentSize = REQUIRED_RECT.size;
    popoverView.frame = REQUIRED_RECT;
});
```